# Overriding doctrine entity manager at runtime

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.3

I'm trying to create a demo system in my Symfony2 project to allow creation of a temporary sqlite demo database for each 'demo' user that logs into a system I'm working on so that each user has access to a default set of data and can modify the data without interfering with other demo users logged into the system.

I've started this by defining a demo connection and an orm entry containing reference to all bundles I want to redirect to the temp db in config.yml then overriding the connection details (more precisely the db path) on login to contain the session id of the user logged in.  So in theory, when they login they'll have access to a default set of demo data and when they logout, no changes are persisted and there changes were only visible by them.

> $this->doctrine->resetManager('demo');

The problem is, when I try to modify the demo connection to point to a new path, when I call the above step (as mentioned on a few posts I've found scattered around the interwebs) the system dies with an error I'm not familiar with and not sure how to tackle.  If somebody could help me understand what's going wrong I should be able to fix it but at the moment I've hit a brick wall :(

Error output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzfQs.png

The process is:

- Demo user logs in (in_memory, none database stored)
- Login listener overrides 'demo' entity manager, changing the DB location to /tmp/portal_demo_[SESSION_ID].db and populating it with demo data
- All following database calls should then use demo database

Here's my code:

## Config.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
      default_connection: default
      connections:
        demo:
          driver:   pdo_sqlite
        default:
          driver:   "%database_driver%"
          host:     "%database_host%"
          port:     "%database_port%"
          dbname:   "%database_name%"
          user:     "%database_user%"
          password: "%database_password%"
          charset:  UTF8
          # Following added to allow importing of existing mysql database. DZH
          mapping_types:
              enum:       string
orm:
  default_entity_manager: default
  entity_managers:
    default:
      connection: default
      mappings:
        SPSettingsBundle: ~
        SPUserBundle: ~
        SPCompanyBundle: ~
        SPVenueBundle: ~
        SPAccessBundle: ~
        SPHardwareBundle: ~
        SPResellerBundle: ~
        SPVouchersBundle: ~
        SPTokenBundle: ~
        SPAdminBundle: ~
        SPSocialBundle: ~
    demo:
      connection: demo
      mappings:
        SPUserBundle: ~
        SPCompanyBundle: ~
        SPVenueBundle: ~
        SPAccessBundle: ~
        SPHardwareBundle: ~
        SPResellerBundle: ~
        SPVouchersBundle: ~
        SPTokenBundle: ~
        SPAdminBundle: ~
        SPSocialBundle: ~
        SPLegacyPortalBundle:
          type: "annotation"
          dir: "Entity"
        SPLegacyPortalBundle:
          type: "annotation"
          dir: "Entity/Radius"
```

## Listener

```
<?php

namespace SP\DemoBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;

class DemoLoginListener {

    private $defaultConnection;
    private $doctrine;
    private $kernel;

    public function __construct(Connection $defaultConnection, Registry $doctrine, KernelInterface $kernel) {
        $this->defaultConnection = $defaultConnection;
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
    }

    /**
     * Create initial database schema
     */
    public function createDbSchema() {
        $application = new \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application($this->kernel);
        $application->setAutoExit(false);

        // Run initial schema install
        $application->run(new ArrayInput(array(
            'doctrine:schema:create',
            '--em' => 'demo'
        )));
    }

    /**
     * Populate database with demo data
     */
    public function populateDemoData() {
        $query = <<<EOT
INSERT INTO `Company` (`account_manager_id`, `package_id`, `name`, `owner_first_name`, `owner_last_name`, `telephone`, `mobile`, `email`, `venues`, `created_by`, `date_created`) VALUES
(NULL, NULL, 'Demo Company', 'Demo', 'User', NULL, NULL, 'demo@company.com', 'N;', 1, '2013-05-16 15:06:16');
EOT;
        $this->defaultConnection->query($query);
    }

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event) {
        $token = $event->getAuthenticationToken();
        $user = $token->getUser();

        // Only create demo database with the 'demo' in_memory user logs in
        if ('demo' == $user->getUsername()) {
            $request = $event->getRequest();
            $session = $request->getSession();

            if ($session) {
                $db_name = sprintf('/tmp/portal_demo_%s.db', $session->getId());

                $this->defaultConnection->close();

                $reflectionConn = new \ReflectionObject($this->defaultConnection);
                $reflectionParams = $reflectionConn->getProperty('_params');
                $reflectionParams->setAccessible('public');

                $params = $reflectionParams->getValue($this->defaultConnection);
                $params['driver'] = 'pdo_sqlite';
                $params['dbname'] = $db_name;
                $params['path'] = $db_name;
                unset($params['host']);
                unset($params['port']);
                unset($params['password']);
                unset($params['user']);

                $reflectionParams->setValue($this->defaultConnection, $params);
                $reflectionParams->setAccessible('private');

                $this->doctrine->resetManager('demo');

                // $this->defaultConnection->connect();
            }
        }

        // Create the naked database
        // $this->createDbSchema();

        // Populate the database with demo data
        // $this->populateDemoData();
    }

}
```